# SQL version of Mysql INT(6)

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to define length of an integer for a sql column.
How do i do this in SQL?

In MySQL it is `INT(6)` for example, which allows `123456` but not `1234567`

Comment: 4 bytes.  The documentation is very clear on this:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html.  There might be additional overhead for `NULL` bits.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I've reworded the Q.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Ah finalllly found it. NUMERIC(6,0)